# Apply a texture to a UI.Graphic inherited Object

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to display a mesh inside the Unity UI. My class inherits from UI.Graphic. I managed to make it work for my vertices and colors, but it seems I can't set a texture to the mesh. I tried different things but nothing worked :

- Tried to set the `material` field on the `CanvasRenderer`
- Tried to set the `material` field on the `Graphic`

The documentation on all this is very bad, and lots of code samples I found (mostly on how to set vertices) were out of date.

Here is the code where I set my vertices :

```
protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
{
    base.OnPopulateMesh(vh);
    vh.Clear();
    if( m_SkinData != null )
    {
        int j = 0;
        foreach( SkinVertex vert in m_SkinData.m_Vertices )
        {
            float channel = j / (float)m_SkinData.m_Vertices.Count;
            Color32 col = new Color(channel, channel, channel);
            vh.AddVert(m_Vertice[j], col, m_uv[j]);
            j++;
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < m_SkinData.m_Indices.Count; i += 3 )
        {
            vh.AddTriangle(m_SkinData.m_Indices[i], m_SkinData.m_Indices[i + 1], m_SkinData.m_Indices[i + 2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result :
[image]

and here is the Material with the diffuse set by code :

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find what.

[Edit] The exact same code is working if it inherits from `UI.Image` instead of `UI.Graphic`. It does not work if it inherits from `UI.MaskableGraphic` (Child of `UI.Graphic`, parent of `UI.Image`). I don't even have to set a sprite or whatever. It's really odd and I'd still like to understand why and what should be the correct way. But for the time being it's a workaround.[/Edit]

Comment: What about meshrenderer?

Comment: As far as I understood and tried, a meshRenderer is always drawn under the UI.

Comment: you've tried?
 - CanvasRenderer.SetTexture(Texture texture) 
- CanvasRenderer.SetMesh (Mesh mesh)

Comment: My material has a `mainTexture` set so I guess the texture should be set when doing a `SetMaterial` on the `CanvasRenderer`. I tried to set the Texture alone too, just to be sure, but no more luck.